# Renew table of contents level and pdf bookmarks

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, hyperref, bookmarks, labbook

I'm using the `labbook` class which uses the commands `\labday`, `\experiment`, and `\subexperiment` as the 0,1,2 table of contents levels. I want to add my own chapters with TOC level of 1 and have the `\labday`, `\experiment`, and `\subexperiment` have TOC levels of 2,3,4. Additionally, I want to have the PDF bookmarks as sub-bookmarks as appropriate.

> How can I alter the TOC level for custom sectioning commands?

The `labbook` documentation gives the following commands for setting these levels:

```
\providecommand*{\toclevel@labday}{0}% 
\providecommand*{\toclevel@experiment}{1}% 
\providecommand*{\toclevel@subexperiment}{2}%
```

which I have tried to modify in the following (perhaps, not so minimal) example

```
\documentclass[idxtotoc, hyperref, openany]{labbook}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\title{Testing Some \texttt{labbook} Modifications}
\author{Jeremy Lloyd Conlin}

% Modifying commands to make bookmarks and such work appropriately
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\toclevel@labday}{1}%
\renewcommand*{\toclevel@experiment}{2}%
\renewcommand*{\toclevel@subexperiment}{3}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\maketitle

\mainmatter

\chapter{Year 1}
\labday{The First}
\experiment{Programming}
\subexperiment[helloworld.c]{\texttt{helloworld.c}}
I am programming in \texttt{C}.

\labday{The Second}
\experiment{Programming}
\subexperiment[helloworld.f90]{\texttt{helloworld.f90}}
I am programming in \texttt{fortran}.

\chapter{Year 2}
\labday{The First}
\experiment{Documenting}
\subexperiment[helloworld.c]{\texttt{helloworld.c}}
I am documenting \texttt{C}.

\labday{The Second}
\experiment{Documenting}
\subexperiment[helloworld.f90]{\texttt{helloworld.f90}}
I am documenting \texttt{fortran}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is that `\labdays` are treated as chapters, and identified as such rather than as `labday`s in the `aux` and `toc` files. Hence the `\toclevel@labday` never gets considered for the bookmarks (and this also explains the warnings about missing out a bookmark level).

The following patches `\labday` so that it gets treated as a section instead of as a chapter (just by replacing `\addchap` with `\addsec` in that macro), though note that there may be other areas that still expect `labday`s to be chapters that this does not touch.

(I have also changed one of the class options to `labbook` as per the warning from newer package versions, and disabled `hypertexnames` in `hyperref` to prevent duplicate destinations.)

```
\documentclass[index=totoc, hyperref, openany]{labbook}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\title{Testing Some \texttt{labbook} Modifications}
\author{Jeremy Lloyd Conlin}

% Modifying commands to make bookmarks and such work appropriately
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\labday}{\addchap}{\addsec}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\toclevel@labday}{1}%
\renewcommand*{\toclevel@experiment}{2}%
\renewcommand*{\toclevel@subexperiment}{3}%
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\maketitle

\mainmatter

\chapter{Year 1}
\labday{The First}
\experiment{Programming}
\subexperiment[helloworld.c]{\texttt{helloworld.c}}
I am programming in \texttt{C}.

\labday{The Second}
\experiment{Programming}
\subexperiment[helloworld.f90]{\texttt{helloworld.f90}}
I am programming in \texttt{fortran}.

\chapter{Year 2}
\labday{The First}
\experiment{Documenting}
\subexperiment[helloworld.c]{\texttt{helloworld.c}}
I am documenting \texttt{C}.

\labday{The Second}
\experiment{Documenting}
\subexperiment[helloworld.f90]{\texttt{helloworld.f90}}
I am documenting \texttt{fortran}.

\printindex
\end{document}
```

The bookmarks and table of contents then look like this, which I believe is what you want:

[image: image of output with above patch]

Comment: This works well. Thanks! How come we don't have to patch the `\experiment` or `\subexperiment` commands?

Comment: @Jeremy: `\experiment` uses `\@startsection{experiment}...` and similarly for `\subexperiment`, so they get correctly identified in the `toc` and `aux` files and hence the `\toclevel@...` stuff works for them.

`\labday` however uses `\addchap` instead of something like `\@startsection{labday}...`, and I don't know enough about `labbook` or the base class `scrbook` to change them to issue such. Hence the use akin to `\section` in this patch, which I think is a reasonable solution if you are happy with the outcome.